# Must log in when scraping facebook posts

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping

I am trying to extract comments from public facebook posts, so I've gathered a certain number of posts' URLs and then I started to scrape them one by one, but while I'm running my code several times I got this window below. Apparently, I have to log in, however I want to scrape them without logging in. I've tried to use proxies, but the problem still the same.

Could someone please provide me with an explanation!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1brifbNqVvUE4JzlfJCDdvoM0Pw0LhVDR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. To programmetically interact with Facebook you have to use the API. If not don't be surprised if you get banned.

Comment: Have you thought about using the Facebook scraper https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/ or is that no option for you?

Comment: @anonimostilton actually I am trying to build my own app, though facebook-scraper is just amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think once you are login into **facebook** domain, then you can launch post URL one by one like this :

Ley's say you have a URL list like this :-

```
url = ['https://www.facebook.com/post1', 'https://www.facebook.com/post2', 'https://www.facebook.com/post3', ..]
```

you can iterate to all the post like :

```
url = ['https://www.facebook.com/post1', 'https://www.facebook.com/post2', 'https://www.facebook.com/post3']
s = len(url)
print(s)
for a in range(s):
    driver.get(url[a])
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: When I log in, there will be a higher risk of getting blocked while scraping, besides, I will get other posts on the same web page.

Comment: that was not mentioned in the original question. The above solution is solely for getting rid of login page again and again. if this works, feel free to close this ticket. if the requirement has changed, feel free to create a new ticket.